# currency drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three tables with specified fields/columns in braces:

Country (name,currency_id)
Currency (name)
User (name ,country_id,currency_id)

And my requirement is while creating user selecting upon country, default currency need to be display first and remaining currencies to be displayed in next selection row. EX: if we select USA in country drop down in currency drop down USD need to be display first and remaining currencies in next

my idea is user belongs to any country default currency is his country currency and he has option to select other currencies also.

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my blogpost. You can populate the next dropdown based on the selected value from the first one, or change the order of the values.

http://marcofranssen.nl/knockout-that-cascading-dropdown/